# Python relative path or placeholder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, placeholder

I coded simple code to import merge filter calculate dataframe, but I can use only on my computer. How can I make it usable on any computer, via relative path or a placeholder?

Code for import dataframe is down, and code working only on my machine because file path is hard-coded, I need a solution how to code this to search `.xlsx` on desktop for example.

```
katalog_CJM = pd.read_excel(
    r"C:\Users\adise\Desktop\Catalogue - 20.07.-09.08.2022 - EXAMPLE\10.Katalog_Katalog_CJM_20.07.2022-09.08.2022.xlsx",
    sheet_name='Katalog')
```

Another code for export I need to save on any desktop or documents in windows:

```
Venera_merge.to_excel(
    r"C:\Users\adise\Desktop\Catalogue - 20.07.-09.08.2022 - EXAMPLE\EXPORT PO DOBAVLJACIMA- PROGRAM\Venera.xlsx",
    index=False)
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

From following code you will get path same as `%UserProfile%` and then you can concatenate further path for desktop.

```py
import os
os.environ['USERPROFILE']
```

Output:
`C:\\User\\user_name`